# Using WMI to get SQL Server 2008 version fails

Tags: sql-server, wmi

I'm trying to get the version of SQL Server 2008 and above version using WMI, I'm using the class of ComputerManagement10 and the query of

```
select PropertyStrValue 
from SqlServiceAdvancedProperty 
where PropertyName = \'VERSION\' and ServiceName =\'MSSQL$SQL2008R2SP1'\'
```

where `ServiceName` is the instance of the SQL Server.

I experience a strange problem that the expected result (PropertyStrValue field) I get is different from the regular `select @@version` or the "Right click -> Properties" (of `sqlservr.exe`)

The version WMI gets is "10.51.2500.0" while the original one is "10.50.2500.0"

I checked more than twice to be sure that this is the correct instance, SQL Server, host, etc, but it seems that I am not the only one who experienced this sort of thing.

Does anyone know why is this behavior happening and how to fix it ?

Does anyone know if it's reliable to use WMI to retrieve the version of SQL Server ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on using WMI, but the value from `select @@version` or better `select SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion')` is correct

Also, are [you doing this correctly](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2006/07/29/682254.aspx) in the first place?

Comment: Just curious, why is it better? Relying on string variable rather then system call seems be less reliable

Comment: @abatishchev: It isn't a "string": it's an internal call to the DB engine like a correct WMI call. I suspect the WMI call here is the wrong one (as per my link), doesn't use the same source and OP demonstrates it is wrong...

Comment: But you can call `select SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion1')` but can't `select @@version1`, that's what I mean "reliable" - [propertyname](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx) is not in compile-time verifiable

Comment: Sorry? I mean query compile time, for example, in SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

I want to know the version of SQL Server in my application and your query is useful.

I get the same error !

I find this if you find anything :

[Wrong SQL Version](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/688571/wrong-sql-server-version-in-sql-server-service-properties-when-viewed-in-from-configuration-manager)

Apparently just an error, but it's good for me

[SQL Version list](http://www.sqlsecurity.com/faqs-1/sql-server-versions)

10.50 / 10.51 => 2008 R2

10.00 => 2008